# How to implement queue mechanism in ASP.Net Core 2.1 with AWS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, queue, asp.net-core-2.1

I have `ASP.Net Core 2.1` application with `AWS` as Cloud. And want to implement a Queue mechanism.

I have an API as below.

```cs
public class UserControler : ControllerBase
{
      [HttpPost]
      public asyn Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]UserTO user)
      {
         //Step#1 Insert the user record in the db
         bool flag = await _userService.Add(user).ConfigureAwait(false); // async Task

         //Step#2 If the db operation is successful, send an email to user email
         if(flag)
             await _emailService.Send(user.email).ConfigureAwait(false); //async Task
      }
 }
```

The `HttpResponse` is returned after the two async methods are executed. **But what I want is**

1. Insert the records in db (_userService.Add(user)
2. Then, some queue mechanism where the task of sending email is added to the queue. Return the response to caller
3. Now it will be queue who would be tackling the task of sending email

It's just once case, the queue task could be anything like sendemail or uploadtos3, createsomelog anything etc.

*I have no clue on how can I do this, hence please bear with me for this*.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a queue would be overkill for this instance, but you could definitely use Simple Queue Service for this.

When you insert an item to SQS, you can set it up to have a Lambda function be triggered and pull the item off the queue and process it. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-lambda-function-trigger.html) is a good tutorial from AWS on how this can be done. [The .NET SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/sqs-apis-intro.html) also has some decent documentation and examples on using SQS.

But, if it was me, I would probably just opt for using a Dynamo Stream to trigger a lambda function. Basically, once the row is inserted, you can trigger a lambda function to execute and process some data. So, in your case, upon insert, you can trigger a function to send an email to that user using data from that row itself.

This is an example of the Lambda code that would be executed.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Model;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Amazon.Lambda.DynamoDBEvents;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]

namespace LocalDynamoDbStream
{
    public class Function
    {
        private static readonly JsonSerializer JsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();

        public Task FunctionHandler(DynamoDBEvent dynamoEvent, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine($"Beginning to process {dynamoEvent.Records.Count} records...");

            foreach (var record in dynamoEvent.Records)
            {
                context.Logger.LogLine($"Event ID: {record.EventID}");
                context.Logger.LogLine($"Event Name: {record.EventName}");

                var streamRecordJson = SerializeStreamRecord(record.Dynamodb);
                context.Logger.LogLine("DynamoDB Record:");
                context.Logger.LogLine(streamRecordJson);

                // Do your email here using data from new inserted row
                var email = record.Dynamodb.NewImage["email"].S;
                await _emailService.Send(email).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            context.Logger.LogLine("Stream processing complete.");

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private static string SerializeStreamRecord(StreamRecord streamRecord)
        {
            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, streamRecord);
                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.Tutorial.html).

Comment: For DynamDb row CRUD events, Lambda is in place but has to to do similar for other cases. Even I was thinking for SQS but was not very sure with it. Thanks!

Comment: In that case, definitely check out the .NET tutorials for SQS, there are some good examples. It is pretty simple to work with, but one thing to keep in mind is that there are cases where a single 'queue item' could be processed more than once in some instances (depending on configuration). So code your queue consumer function in a way that can handle being run more than once, but not sending out duplicate emails.